# Duplicated result from MySql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am having a problem that from my SQL statement. When I echo the result, there will be a duplicate result (2 same results) appear.

This is my code below:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
        . "LEFT JOIN employementdetails ed ON apd.ApplicantID = ed.ApplicantID "
        . "LEFT JOIN sourceoffunds sof ON apd.ApplicantID = sof.ApplicantID "
        . "LEFT JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
        . "WHERE apd.AccountID ='{$accountId}' AND applicantType ='main';");        

$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);

        echo $row['EmploymentStatus'];
        ?>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
} 
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Comment: You either have a duplicated row in your data or you get duplicated rows as a result of your joins. Without seeing your data it's impossible to tell. Break up your query in MySQL workbench or the MySQL console into smaller parts until you see which relationship or table is the problem.

Comment: I'm curious about why you're using extract() here. It's not contributing to your problem, but it's not necessary nor helpful in the scope of your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Might be, I m wrong, just consider that.

First:

`AND applicantType ='main'` - this piece seems suspicious, as it does not define its table, and since, it should be complained for the "`unknown column`"

Second:

More than one results generally appear when more then one results are found by the query you apply. Your query does not exclude such situation at all. First, you use `SELECT *` - it means find all. Second, you do not use `LIMIT`, which also means find all. Finally, use `SELECT DISTINCT`, which eliminates duplicates.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Also:

Use `var_dump()` to debug.

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is something wrong with the table, with a duplicate data. existingbankproducts is having 2 data from the same applicant